# Any way to issue telnet commands remotely ander double telnet session?

Tags: python, linux, telnet

What do I need:

```
telnet 1.1.1.1 (no password or login required)
#connected
telnet localhost 1234
command_1
command_2
command_3
exit
exit
```

is there any way to write it on bash or python ?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I think the idea is to connect to a remote machine, connect to a localhost-only service on that, and then send the commands to the localhost-only service.

Comment: @Andrew, this makes sense. I see I was misunderstanding "double telnet session".

Comment: If you really want to do this in Python, you can. Use [`telnetlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) to connect to 1.1.1.1 and then write, e.g., `python <<EOF` followed by another script that uses `telnetlib` for the inner telnet followed by `EOF`… But that would be silly. This is the kind of thing `bash` is good for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass input to telnet using a pipe. At your shell:

```
$ echo "echo -e 'command_1\ncommand_2\ncommand_3' | telnet localhost 1234" | telnet 1.1.1.1
```